# How to delete all entities for NDB Model in Google App Engine for python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a ndb model class:

```
class Game(ndb.Model):
    gameID = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    gameName = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Is there any way to quickly just delete all entities thats stored in the database for this class? Something like `Game.deletAll()`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, but you could easily do this with something like:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

ndb.delete_multi(
    Game.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
)
```

Comment: your `query` is a list of keys: ndb.delete_multi(query)

Comment: You'll be a little bit better if you use `iter` instead of `fetch`